# Diagnosing Sporadic Lockups in Website Running on IIS

Tags: iis

### Goal

Determine the cause of the sporadic lock ups of our web application running on IIS.

### Problem

An application we are running on IIS sporadically locks up throughout the day. When it locks up it will lock up on all workers and on all load balanced instance.

### Environment and Application

The application is running on 4 different Windows Server 2016 machines. The machines are load balanced using ha-proxy using a round robin load balancing scheme. The IIS application pools this website is hosted in are configured to have 4 workers each and the application it hosts is a 32-bit application. The IIS instances are not using a shared configuration file but the application pools for this application are all configured the same.

This application is the only application in the IIS application pool. The application is an ASP.NET web API and is using .NET 4.6.1. The application is not creating threads of its own.

### Theory

My theory for why this is happening is that we have requests that are coming in that are taking ~5-30 minutes to complete. Every machine gets tied up servicing these requests so they look "locked up". The company rolled their own logging mechanism and from that I can tell we have requests that are taking ~5-30 minutes to complete. The team responsible for the application has cleaned up many of these but I am still seeing ~5 minute requests in the log.

I do not have access to the machines personally so our systems team has gotten memory dumps of the application when this happens. In the dumps I generally will see ~50 threads running and all of them are in our code. These threads will be all over our application and do not seem to be stopped on any common piece of code. When the application is running correctly the dumps have 3-4 threads running. Also I have looked at performance counters like the ASP.NET\Requests Queued but it never seems to have any requests queued. During these times the CPU, Memory, Disk and Network usage look normal. Using windbg none of the threads seem to have a high CPU time other than the finalizer thread which as far as I know should live the entire time.

### Conclusion

I am looking for a means to prove or disprove my theory as to why we are locking up as well as any metrics or tools I should look at.

Comment: If you know how to use a tool like WinDbg, debug the web app and confirm what's the culprit. If you don't know enough, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com. There might be other commercial/free tools, but recommendations on such are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue came down to our application using query in stitch on a table with 2,000,000 records in it to another table. Memory would become so fragmented that the Garbage Collector was spending more time trying to find places to put objects and moving them around than it was running our code. This is why it appeared that our application was still working and why their was no exceptions. Oddly IIS would time out the requests but would continue processing the threads.